# Knockout.js before and after examples?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Im learning Knockout.js through online tutorials, and even though I understand them I dont  fully see how it makes things easier.

For example even though I understand this http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LkqTU/

```
    this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
```

i dont see how its a significant improvement over something like this    http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LkqTU/

```
function updateBox2() {  var x=document.getElementById("first1");
document.getElementById('full').innerText = x.value}
```

but that was of course an extremely basic example. (The code samples here arent too good, better to check out the jsfiddle).

So my question is, does anyone have code examples whereby the first code performs an action using regular javascript and the second does the same but this time using knockoutjs and clearly shows how its a big improvement?

Comment: ... Now write a *big* application, doing everything manually.

Comment: Learning is a hard work and takes time, play with knockoutjs a bit. A little hint, try using templates, u will find it amusing.

Comment: Check out the [KO mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) which really helped me to see where KO two-way binding could save me lots of time.  The mapping plugin creates most of your observables for you automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to compare vanilla JavaScript with KnockoutJS, I would try to understand how *data-binding* pattern simplifies client development.

Do you imagine your UI automatically reacting to a model change, and viceversa? Do you imagine that by just configuring the whole bindings?

With data-binding, your JavaScript will rarely need to manipulate the DOM, because the proper KnockoutJS binding will handle a lot of things for you and without your intervention.

Thus, you concentrate your efforts on manipulating the model as response to UI changes (invoked by KnockoutJS). And the UI changes automatically when you change the model.

For example, if you bind an observable array called `items` to a view like this:

```
<ol data-bind="foreach: items">
   <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ol>
```

...and you want to show 3 items in your view, it's just about doing so:

```
viewModel.items.push("Hello");
viewModel.items.push("world");
viewModel.items.push("!");
```

KnockoutJS adds new `<li />` elements to your ordered list because the UI reacts to the whole `items` array changes.

Now *try to use your mind, be formless and be like water*, and I'm pretty sure you should be able to compare what extra-work would be required without using data-binding, and how many code lines may you save in a real-world project using this approach!